# Copyright violation, dirty pool, or just a coincidence?

Tags: support

There's a new Google+/Blogspot Android resource offering, among other things, a weekly Hangout to talk about Android stuff.

Its name? **Android Enthusiasts**

- https://plus.google.com/103783886144374597555/posts
- http://androidenthusiasts.blogspot.com/

<s>It seems to me</s> Somebody might think they're sponging off of our name. Even if it's not some sort of violation it seems rather dirty.

Comment: Perhaps it's an honest mistake? Maybe they don't suspect the existence of Android-SE. I mean, is "Android Enthusiasts" so popular that it can be considered a "trademarked" name of sorts? Perhaps contacting the hangout hosts can help with working things out.

Comment: We are the first hit in Google for "Android Enthusiasts", but you don't see that in the result -- it just says Android.  You'd have to actually come here to see the name.  Perhaps that's something the team should address.

Comment: Indeed, I think the team does need to address it. Hence why I tagged this with "support".

Comment: @AlEverett I'll pass this up the chain. Thanks!

Comment: Even if it's not trademark violation and putting aside the question of "dirtiness", due to the popularity of StackExchange, Android.SE has a very good search engine ranking; it would be in Derek's best interest to avoid competing for "Android Enthusiast" keyword as it might confuse people in his community who are googling for his blog that are unaware of the difference between this Android Enthusiast and that Android Enthusiast, especially once we had our own community blog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just got a message from Derek Ross on G+.

> Hello +Al Everett +Anna Lear +Laura Dobrzynski,
>
> I would like to respond to your post
>   [Copyright violation, dirty pool, or just a coincidence?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/865/copyright-violation-dirty-pool-or-just-a-coincidence).
>   I would have loved to respond on that website, however I am not a
>   member. I tried to create an account but I need 5 rep to respond or
>   answer the topic. Whatever that means... Probably to cut down on spam.
>   Anyways...
>
> I was viewing our traffic stats for our blog and I noticed them coming
>   from this website. I had never heard of this website, so I visited it
>   and found this thread.
>
> +Scott Anderson and myself have been loosely calling ourselves Android Enthusiasts for years now. Neither of us had ever visited nor heard of
>   this website. No disrespect, dirty pool or any type of copyright
>   violation was ever intended. As the term Android Enthusiast is so
>   generic, this is just a mere coincidence.
>
> With that said, we're huge fans of all things Android as it seems
>   members of your site are as well. We would love for anyone from your
>   site to join our weekly show. We welcome any and all Android
>   enthusiasts from that vast community that surrounds Android. Let us
>   know if you're interested and we'll try to find a topic that is
>   relevant.
>
> Feel free to post this on the original website thread for me as I
>   cannot. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for following up on it, Al.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, the name "Android Enthusiasts" is so close to generic that it's very unlikely we'd be able to stop them from using it.

However, our wonderful core developers have told me it's pretty easy to make that hyperlink in the Google results say "Android Enthusiasts - Stack Exchange" rather than "Android - Stack Exchange," so that change will be implemented soon.

If you're looking to become their friends, maybe a representative from this site could join one of their future hangouts as a special guest? Just a suggestion; interact or don't interact with them as you wish. :) As Matthew Read pointed out, this site is the top Google hit when searching "Android Enthusiasts" so there's nothing to worry about right now. They probably just didn't know this site exists and already uses the name they decided to adopt a week ago.

Comment: But their site is the top one in Bing :P